# Fargate: Sending email to private smtp server on port 25

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, smtp, amazon-ecs

I'm using AWS Fargate as my container platform.  My container base image is openjdk:8-alpine and the application is a spring-boot app.  I'm attempting to use JavaMailSender to send emails over a vpn tunnel to our internal SMTP server on port 25.  This works while testing the container locally, using the same SMTP server.

I've mainly used this guide https://www.baeldung.com/spring-email for the email functionality in my spring boot app.

If I add the following commands to the docker entrypoint I test hostname resolving and telnet connection.  The host and dig commands always work.  Sometimes telnet works and other times it will timeout, causing a re-deployment of the container.  When sending emails I see the same behavior.  Some emails will send while others fail due to a timeout connecting to the SMTP server.

```
## Dockerfile

FROM openjdk:8-alpine

COPY core/target/app.jar /app/app.jar

WORKDIR /app

CMD CMD host $my_smtp_server \
       && dig $my_smtp_server \
       && telnet $my_smtp_server 25 \
       && java -jar $app.jar

EXPOSE 8080 25
```

```java
## application.properties

# Mail config
#------------
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8
spring.mail.host=$my_smtp_server
spring.mail.port=25
spring.mail.protocol=smtp

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=false
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
#------------
```

Emails should send every time I invoke the function in my application.

Answer (score 0):

A response I got from AWS.

In response to your last correspondence, I understand that you you want to remove the restriction on port 25 from your ECS cluster. The internal team have looked into your query and found that currently Fargate infrastructure doesn't support Port# 25 (SMTP); and the existing workaround is to use EC2 launch type and then request for the Port #25 throttling to be removed in your account [1].

Comment: At the end you have "[1]" - is there supposed to be a link there?

Answer (score 0):

Just putting it out there for others: our Fargate sitting behind a private Subnet uses a NAT GW (in public subnet ofcrs) to send emails outside, and we have successfully got the  email-sending-limitations lifted from AWS for that NAT GW! Happy ending!